# Android:While calling default fragment to another fragment getting Invalid Id error

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image][image]

i am working with Navigation drawer Layout, My aim is to show default Fragment when page application open, if i want to move another PageViewer activity it is showing this below error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{blackmonk.mobile.activity/blackgm.mobile.activity.ArtcilesCateActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0068 (blackmonk.mobile.activity:id/main_content) for fragment ApplicationHome{41db82e8 #0 id=0x7f0d0068}


03-07 09:32:55.341: E/AndroidRuntime(13304): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0068 (blackgm.mobile.activity:id/main_content) for fragment ApplicationHome{41db82e8 #0 id=0x7f0d0068}
```

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    moveDrawerToTop();
    initActionBar();
    initDrawer();
//calling default fragment
FragmentManager fm1 = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
    fragment = new ApplicationHome();
    ft1.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
    ft1.commit();
}   private void moveDrawerToTop() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.decr,
            null); // "null" is important.
    ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
    View child = decor.getChildAt(0);
    decor.removeView(child);
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) drawer
            .findViewById(R.id.drawer_content); // This is the container we
                                                // defined just now.
    container.addView(child, 0);
    drawer.findViewById(R.id.topBar).setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0,
            0);
    // Make the drawer replace the first child
    decor.addView(drawer);
//on onclick 
if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(left_drawer);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_content" >
</FrameLayout>
```

And i have added separate onclicks for all items
now i would like to show default , i am able to show ,but when i am calling activity its crashing

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: check..i updated my code

Comment: LogCat as photoshop project,,. Impressive :)

Comment: thanx but i need an answer

Comment: This is missing the layout xml, but from my guess, `R.id.main_content` isn't a valid view of the containing activity/fragment.

Comment: i added my xml code ...check now

Answer (score 0):

Try this `activity_main` layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <FrameLayout          
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:id="@+id/main_content" >
   </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check i updated my code,i am calling Fragment two times.first time on Oncreate , 2nd time on onclick while replacing fragment i am giving same R.id.main_content.

Comment: Yes your error show first call `onCreate`, means your `R.id.main_content` not available. So you should check your layout file `activity_main.xml`

Comment: actually i am calling one default fragment when app opens, and onclick i am calling different activity as well as fragment at a a time[page swiper].thats why its showing invalid ID.so I myslef found solution like   just i am checking every time FRAGMENT null or not finally i have resolved . Thanx for your response